# How do I get content to expand to 100% should their be no sidebar content?

Tags: html, css, drupal, layout, css-float

I'm creating my own theme for drupal, and would like it so when there is no sidebar, the content width is 100%, and when there is a sidebar, the content shrinks horizontally to allow room for the sidebar. Here's an example of the structure:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='content'></div>
   <div id='sidebar'></div>
</div>
```

[image]

All I have managed to achieve so far is the image furthest right, where the content wraps around it.

I'd much prefer to do this using css only.

Comment: It seems that this is ideal to be done on the server side. Is that at all possible?

Comment: @michaelward82 Probably, but I have no real experience with drupal or php so I wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the sidebar first in the markup and position it absolutely.  Then use the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) to give the content a right margin when it follows a sidebar:

```
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
#sidebar + #content {
    margin-right: 150px;
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/cH4ZY/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you can add a class to the container when there is no sidebar, then you can do this.

```
#container.wide #content {
    width: 100%;
}
#container.wide #sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your drupal *non-sidebar* html structure is this:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div id='content'></div>
</div>
```

Then adding the below css after your typical `content` styling will cause the 100% width to occur only when there is just the `content` div in the `container`, because it will then be the `last-child` of the container. When the `sidebar` is present, the `sidebar` will be the `last-child` and this CSS is not triggered for the `content`.

```
#container > #content:last-child {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just tweak two different base themes (one with, and one without, a sidebar), and then use a module like [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) to determine which parts of your site display which theme. I tend to use single-column themes for "Admin" stuff, but it's easy to work on customizing your own to have the same "look and feel" as your 2 or 3-column one which you might display on most content pages.

You can also have a theme that changes, but it's probably easier to select a similar theme (e.g. with single column) for some pages than to dynamically change a lot about one theme and have it display in different ways in different parts of your site.